# What is the sum of the $n^2$ terms obtained this way?

Tags: linear-algebra

We multiply each entry of an $n × n $ matrix A by the cofactor belonging to it. What is the sum of the
$n^2$ terms obtained this way?

I dont understand how a cofactor can belong it entry. Does it mean one cofactor is same for each entry of according row or column?(according to Expansion theorem).

Comment: comment this below the related answer

Comment: I have accepted answer I wrote this comment before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the determinant of a matrix is given by the sum of the entries of any row or column multiplied by their cofactors. So the result you want is just $n\cdot\det{(A)}$ by calculating the determinant over every row or every column and adding the results.